# Using RegExp in SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

This is the code in VB Script, how would it be done if i was to build a function called dbo.FileNameEncode(str) in SQL Server ?

```
Function FileNameEncode(ByVal strFileName)     
    Dim oReg     
    strFileName = LTrim(Rtrim(strFileName))
    Set oReg = New RegExp     
    oReg.IgnoreCase = True     
    oReg.Global = True     
    oReg.Pattern = "[^a-z\d\s.]+"     
    FileNameEncode = Replace(oReg.Replace(strFileName, ""), " ", "_")     
    Set oReg = Nothing 
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it as a SQL Server [CLR stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx).

- [Creating CLR Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190790.aspx)
- [Choosing between CLR and T-SQL stored procedures](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/choosing-between-clr-and-t-sql-stored-procedures-a-simple-benchmark/)